# How to unit test a custom Wicket component

Tags: java, unit-testing, components, wicket, wicket-tester

Given this really simple Wicket component:

```
public class ProductImage extends WebComponent {

    public ProductImage(String id, Product p) {
        super(id, new Model(p));
        add(new AttributeModifier("src", true, new Model(p.getImage())));
    }
}
```

How to unit test it using WicketTester? Do I need a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't actually done that (I've only [tested panels](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#startPanel%28org.apache.wicket.util.tester.ITestPanelSource%29)), but [`startComponent()`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/util/tester/BaseWicketTester.html#startComponent%28org.apache.wicket.Component%29) seems to be the way to do it.

Something like this:

```
Product product = new Product(/* initialize product here */);
ProductImage pi = new ProductImage("image", product);
tester.startComponent(pi);
tester.assertContains(Pattern.quote(product.getImage()));
```

Comment: hmmm, almost there! Really `startComponent` seems to be the way, but I cannot manage to test if "src" attribute is correct.

Comment: @Eduardo not explicitly, but you can test like this: `tester.assertContains("src\\s*=\\s*\"" + Pattern.quote(product.getImage()) + "\"");`

Comment: that's what I thought, but your first example fails :( Digging into Wicket's source, I found assertContains works on tester.getServletResponse().getDocument(), and this is empty after startComponent!

Comment: @Eduardo then I guess you'll need a panel after all.

Comment: :( Lot's of trouble for something as simple as that

Comment: @Eduardo true, but there's still probably no other web framework where unit testing is that easy

Answer (score 6):

In Wicket 1.5 there is #startComponentInPage(Component) which will create a page for you so you can test any kind of component.

Comment: That's nice... Too bad I'm stuck with 1.4 for a while! But thanks, anyway!